# socket.io downloading on every page load

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, socket.io

socket.io doesn't appear to cache like other js files.  I have a pretty large web application, and I put a link to socket.io.js in the header, and it's getting hammered (around 500KB/s).  Any ideas on how to prevent the js file from downloading every time, and just using a cached copy like every other remote js file on the site?

Thanks

Comment: How are you serving the JS file?

Comment: yuo can host the client lib yourself instead of having socket.io do it, which should make it behave like the other script files you use. there's advice on the site about that.

Comment: I've never had this problem, but I also use Socket.IO with Express and other modules.  Are you using Socket.IO straight-up?  Show some code.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look [at the Socket.io wiki](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO#wiki-configuring-socketio). There are plenty of server side options that affect delivery and caching of the `socket.io.js` file.

The `browser client etag` option might help you. But there are also other options that could be interesting if you want to optimize entire file handling.

Otherwise, as already mentioned in the comments, you can host a copy of the `socket.io.js` file just like your other static files. Don`t forget to update it after switching socket.io versions.